# How to calculate the Expected value of the estimator (simplification with combinatorial manipulation)

Tags: statistics, combinations

The following table shows the Expected Value and Variance for 4 estimators. Each of the 4 estimators are used to estimate the size of a population through a random sample.

**Note that, X_n is the largest value of the random sample, and X_1 is the smallest value in the randomly selected sample. N is the population size.**

[Table with Expected Value and Variance of Estimators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYLT.png)

I want to prove the Expected Value for Estimator 3, and I have made some progress.

Since E(N_3) = E(X_n) + E(X_1) - 1; I have managed to determine E(X_n) to be n(N+1)/(n+1) as shown below:
[Part 1 of Simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHEqJ.png)
[Part 2 of Simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTO0v.png)

Now, I tried to use the same approach with E(X_1), but I'm not able to proceed beyond a certain point:
[Proof for X_1, attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl419.png)

**I know based on the results, that E(X_1) has to be (N+1)/(n+1)**

Any ideas on how to proceed?

I'm trying to simplify the combination so that the parameter k is part of the combination, and thus can be replaced using a result from the probabilities adding up to 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As written, this question appears to be asking for general statistics advice; it may more appropriate for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Questions here must be about a specific programming problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed.). Please adjust your question according to the recommendations at the link or it may be closed.